# Exporting from illustrator to A4

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I know its basic, but i have an `A4` artboard in `Illustrator` .
I would like to send it to printing , and they want it to be in `pdf`.

I afraid that the sizes definitions will change.

So, when i export it as `png`, what `PPI` should i use ? the `72` ? can i use higher(150/300) one and keep the sizes the same ?

I am on a mac so latter i open it with `preview` and export to `pdf` .

Comment: Why not export directly from Illustrator as PDF, without converting through png & preview?

Answer (score 1):

To turn any Illustrator file into a High-Res, Print-Ready PDF, you can just use the File > Save As dialogue and choose "PDF" from your file type.

In order to keep it high resolution and perfect for print, the easiest way is to use the [High Quality] Illustrator default from the PDF options dialogue.

The main thing you want is Illustrator to not "downsample" the work you've created to a low resolution. If you're doing this manually, it is within the Compression tab of the PDF save options.

Comment: Downsampling in Illustrator applies only to placed raster graphics. Content created in Illustrator itself being vector-based, downsampling does not apply.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that is a very good point. As the user didn't specify what variety of items he had in his file, I thought it would be best to cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

First, don´t be afraid, if you create A4 file and you save it, they´ll be in A4 size and its not gonna change ( so, if you go to print and you don´t select A4 in your print settings they´ll change, take care of it)

To save your PDF to optimal print always save it in "High Quality Print" (if you want to make lighter file unmark "Preserve illustrator editing capabilities" this let you posible email sending)

[image: Save PDF settings]

To save docs for print in .png always in 300 ppi (previous check the "use artboard box" for correct size)

[image]

[image: Export png settings]